# Force references to be the same in different refsections

Tags: biblatex

I have a document with a common bibliography at the end and short bibliographies for each section. How do I force the reference ids for the same paper to be the same across the document?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    sorting=nyt,
    natbib=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{test.bib}
@Article{test1,
  author =   {First Author},
  title =    {First very interesting paper},
  journal =  {International Journal},
  year =     2022,
}

@Article{test2,
  author =   {First Author},
  title =    {Second very interesting paper},
  journal =  {International Journal},
  year =     2022,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
The material in this section is based on paper \cite{test1} (paper \cite{test2} is not relevant here).
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{test1}
  \newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]
  \printbibliography[
    heading=none
  ]  
\end{refsection}

\section{Body of the paper}
...

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this (notice the highlighted references):
[image: Generated output for the MWE]

I want the first paper to be referenced the same ("[Aut22a]") across the document. I do not want to put the text of Section 1 ("The material...") inside the `refsection`, since that would include the second paper in the citations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`refsection`s create independent units with their own label. Use `refsegment` and then filter by the segment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    sorting=nyt,
    natbib=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{test.bib}
@Article{test1,
  author =   {First Author},
  title =    {First very interesting paper},
  journal =  {International Journal},
  year =     2022,
}

@Article{test2,
  author =   {First Author},
  title =    {Second very interesting paper},
  journal =  {International Journal},
  year =     2022,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
The material in this section is based on paper \cite{test1} (paper \cite{test2} is not relevant here).
\begin{refsegment}
  \nocite{test1}
  \newrefcontext[sorting=ynt]
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,
    heading=none
  ]
\end{refsegment}

\section{Body of the paper}
...

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Ulrike! I tried `refsegment` some time ago but did not notice the filtering (`segment=\therefsegment`). That's exactly what I neeeded